# Typescript. ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I read official [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) for TypeScript, and I copy code from there.

I  install commonjs and requerejs.

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "commonjs": "latest",
  "requirejs": "latest"
}
```

But I get a error in the browser:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

It is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
     <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

It is main.js after compiling:

```
"use strict";
var core_1 = require("./some_dir/some_file");
window.onload = function () {
    var some = new some_file_1.SomeClass();
};
```

Comment: How are you running your program? Also: are you using a bundler?

Comment: I'm use PyCharm. Run->Run 'index.html'

Comment: So how do you include all your js files into the html page? just include every .js file as a new script tag?

Comment: I include main.js only. Like example above. It is bad? Can I hear true way for TypeScript helloworld project in PyCharm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers don't have a understanding of modules (yet). That means while require() works if you execute it in node only, browsers don't know what to do with it.

There are 2 main methods of fixing this:

- Remove the `exports/require` statements and include every single js file (in correct dependency order) into your html file (as script tags). They will all have the same scope and will work as if there was just one large concatenated file. This solution is pretty bad tho as it destroys scoping, doesn't really work with modules you got with npm and has bad loading times, as it has to fetch multiple js files from the server.
- Use a resource bundler like `webpack`. Webpack will look at all dependant files starting from your `main.js` file and bundle and compress them down into a single small `.js` file. This also works for external dependencies (npm). All you have to do then is to include that single `bundle.js` file into the html.

Comment: Wow, I try webpack, and it is working. It's a bit complicated, but I think that there is a benefit. Thanks!