# why is typescript generating javascript that chrome doesn't accept?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome

I think I must be missing something very basic in typescript.   I use tsc to compile two .ts files that both reference another .ts module.   I get two errors from chrome for the .js that is generated,

> require is not defined

> Identifier 'util_1' has already been declared.

Toy example that recreates the problem below.

Folder structure is html and html/js.

html has index.html

html/js has file1.{ts,js} file2.{ts,js} util.{ts,js}

html/index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 
<head> 
    <title>This is the title</title> 
</head> 
 
<body> 
    <!-- Main Page --> 
    <h1>This is a header</h1> 
    <p>Hello, world 
      <!--- work around exports undefined error ---> 
    <script>var exports = {}</script> 
 
    <script src="js/file1.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/file2.js"></script> 
</body>
```

file1.ts is

```
import {L} from './util' 
L("I am file1")
```

file2.ts is

```
import {L} from './util' 
L("I am file2")
```

util.ts is

```
export function L(x:any) {console.log( x)}
```

The generated .js that results is
file1.js

```
"use strict"; 
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); 
const util_1 = require("./util"); 
util_1.L("I am file1");
```

file2.js

```
"use strict"; 
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); 
const util_1 = require("./util"); 
util_1.L("I am file2");
```

and util.js

```
"use strict"; 
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); 
exports.L = void 0; 
function L(x) { console.log(x); } 
exports.L = L;
```

Note the double definition of **const util_1** in the two .js files, and the **require** that the browser doesn't like.   What am I doing wrong!?

---

Added after comments: I should have included tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
      "lib": ["es5","es6","es7",
          "es2015","es2016",
          "es2017","es2018","es2019","dom" ], /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing `target` is set to node?

Comment: The compiler is transforming your ES2015 `import` and `export` into old-school `require` syntax, which browsers do not natively support. Your Typescript setup needs adjustment.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790590/typescript-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your settings in `tsconfig.json` are incorrect for the browser context. Take a look at this guide for a good starting point: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/browser